# Jquery Ajax Boolean Variable is not working well

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
 $.validator.addMethod("checkUsername", 
   function(value, element){
    var test;     //we want to use this test is like boolean variable
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",            
        data: 'name='+ value,
        url: "master/ValidationDepartment.jsp",
        success: function(response){  
               test = true;   //assign this value is true                
        },
        error: function() {
               test = false;  //assign this value is false 
    }
    });
         //alert(test);     // bt now this time test value is undifined
    return test;
  }, 
"Departmentname Already Exists."
);
});
```

I also tried with `var test = true`.
If we declare `test = true` every time its value is true.

Comment: Ajax will run **asynchronously**, meaning your value will return immediately, while the request is still running.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but how should i approach on this problem?

Comment: @BipinBangwal Telling us what you're trying to achieve is a good first step.

Comment: @bipin-bangwal Try setting async to false in your ajax options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as ajax calls will run asynchronously, the value of `test` will only change after your function returns.
To prevent this from happening, set `async: false` in the options of your ajax request.

A similar question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2982669/1705725

Answer (score 0):

The `.ajax()` runs asynchronously and your value will be returned immediately .You can write a callback function in the success or error handler and update the variable . You can set `async:false` but then it will block till the AJAX response returns.

Comment: please give some more detail,i m quite new in jquery.