# Remote validation in a jQuery Mobile not showing Error Msg

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to validate the form using remote ajax.

What I want to achieve is display error message and a cross graphic if the return is false and display a tick without any error message.

I ended up with 2 results,

1) Display message but no graphic because return data is undefined.

2) Display message not fire but graphic works perfectly.

Please find my code below:

1) Display message but no graphic because return data is undefined.

```
rules: {


        username: {

            required: true,

            minlength: 3,

            remote:
            {
              url: "../check_teamname.php",
              type: "POST",
               data:{   
                username: function(data)
                {
                    jQuery('.username').removeClass('cross');
                    jQuery('.username').removeClass('tick');
                    return jQuery('.username').val();

                    console.log(data);
                    if(data !== true){
                        jQuery('.username').addClass('cross');
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        jQuery('.username').addClass('tick');
                        return true;
                    }
                }
              }
            }


        }
```

2) Display message not fire but graphic works perfectly.

```
rules: {


        username: {

            required: true,

            minlength: 3,

            remote:
            {
              url: "../check_teamname.php",
              type: "POST",
              //dataType: "json",
              data:{    
                username: function()
                {
                    jQuery('.username').removeClass('cross');
                    jQuery('.username').removeClass('tick');
                    return jQuery('.username').val();
                }
              },
              //cache: false,
              success: function(msg){

                    console.log(msg);
                    if(msg !== true){
                        jQuery('.username').addClass('cross');

                        return false;
                    }else{
                        jQuery('.username').addClass('tick');
                        return true;
                    }
                },error: function(msg) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    return false;
                }
            }


        }
```

My PHP "check_teamname.php" will echo "true" or "false".

Appreciate if any of you could help to fix it, Thanks!

Comment: Found this with the similar issue, I will give it a try and update the post.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2982669/1835109

Comment: Thank to the above solution, I have tweaked my code and it works now.

My Changes are below:

1) echo my PHP to 1 or 0
2) Using jQuery.validator.addMethod
3) Give an var response = data in success: function(data)
4) Then do my actions outside ajax
 if(response == 1)
    {
 jQuery('.username').addClass('tick');
        return true;
    }
    else{
 jQuery('.username').addClass('cross');
 return false;
   }
});